# In a rails controller, set a notice even when responding with json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, ujs

I have an ajax call that hits my create action.

```
def create
  @post = Post.create(post_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render json: status: "success", location: post_path(@post), notice: "Post was successfully created!" }
    format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: "Post was successfully created!" }
  end
end
```

When I use `post#create` without ajax, I can easily set the `notice` to be shown on the next page. However when I use ajax, I'm not sure how to set the notice. How I can I do this?

Comment: Emily What ajax you used? ruby on rails ajax? or not ? can you post your ajax code?

Comment: Yeah, it's Ruby on Rails ajax. That create action gets hit from a remote form (using UJS).

Answer (score 0):

Do not return json. Render a complete javascript response. Jquery will automatically eval this js coming from you server. Within this js you typically replace some inner_html of a page element with your data from controller. And you can add some js dom manipulation for displaying a notice.

[Unobtrusive Javascript](http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript?view=asciicast)

[Working with Ajax 4 Server-Side Concerns](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#server-side-concerns)

This technique is much faster to implement, than parsing json and add logic on the client. And it allows you to reuse existing html partials, which just render into the js response to places as inner_html.

If you'd really like to stick with json, you would have to modify your json repsonse with some additional info about the notice (so just rendering an active record collection :to_json is not enough)